# pass constant to entity to entity in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have an image processing entity that I want to test. I created a package with several stimulus as constant. and I created a driver to apply the stimulus to the DUT.

assuming this is the stimulus package:

```
  package sim_pkg is

    type pixel is record
      x: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      y: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);     
    end record;   

    type array_pixel is array (natural range <>) of pixel;
    constant array_1 : array_pixel(0 to 2) := 
      (0 => (x"0", x"0"),   
       1 => (x"1", x"1"),  
       2 => (x"2", x"2")  
      );
    constant array_2 : array_pixel(0 to 3) := 
      (0 => (x"0", x"0"),   
       1 => (x"1", x"1"),  
       2 => (x"2", x"2"),
       3 => (x"2", x"2")
      );
    -- more stimulus
    ...
  end package;
```

and a driver that just applies the requested array to the input of the DUT.

```
  entity img_test is
    port(pixel_out : out pixel)
  end entity;

  architecture foo of img_test is  
  begin

    -- here it supposes to receive a constant name, for example array_1, and apply its element to pixel_out?

  end architecture;
```

I am using Vunit, so I want to send a msg to the driver with the stimulus name. I know how to send a msg but I am having a problem figuring out how to tell the driver which stimuli I want to send.

I know that I can have a procedure to apply the stimulus directly from the testbench but I would like to know if it is possible to have a procedure for example **apply_img** that takes a stimulus name in my testbench that asks the driver to apply a specific stimulus.

```
procedure apply_img(start : boolean; some parameter to specify the stimulus);
```

Is it possible to pass a constant name to another entity in a way that this other entity can use the data object that has this name in vhdl

Answer (score 1):

Pushing and popping the individual elements of the record and creating convenience wrapper subprograms is the recommended way in VUnit but let's explore the options.

What you can do is to store your pixel arrays in an associative array/dictionary type of data structure (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) where the key is the name you pass to the driver. The driver can then search that data structure for the data associated with the key.

You can create such a data structure from scratch but you can also use the dictionary type shipped with VUnit (https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/blob/master/vunit/vhdl/data_types/src/dict_pkg.vhd). It can only map a string (like your name) to a string so you would have to encode your pixel arrays to string to make that work. What you can do is to store your pixels using the integer vector pointer type (https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/blob/master/vunit/vhdl/data_types/src/integer_vector_ptr_pkg.vhd) and then use its encode/decode functions. Finally I recommend that you write wrapper functions to do everything in one step.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I read a little bit about the integer_vector_ptr_pkg but I found that it needs more reading and understanding for me. I ended up having a global signal in a package and assign copy my constants to this signal and read it from the driver. it is working but I think I will invest in building a general solution for this.

Comment: I never asked but why trying to send the name rather than just sending the array?

Comment: I send a msg to the driver using Vunti com library and it does not support pushing records. So I have to have a procedure to handle the pushing of each type of record. therefore, I was thinking if there is a way just to send the name of the constant and the type and somehow the driver can refer to that specific constant.